# Get most common values/pattern from a list of lists of objects

Tags: c#, linq

### **Update 2: More concise**

I have this data in my database

[image: Masteries and Rank]

I need to get the most frequent masteries used for a champion. How can I achieve that with LINQ?

This is how I get the data:

```
        List<List<Masteries.Mastery>> MasteryList = new List<List<Masteries.Mastery>>();

        Conex.Command.CommandText = "SELECT masteries FROM matchdetails_participantsdetails_na WHERE championID=@champID;";
        Conex.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@champID", championID);

        using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = Conex.Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                List<Masteries.Mastery> tmpMastery = new List<Masteries.Mastery>();

                tmpMastery = serializer.Deserialize<List<Masteries.Mastery>>(dbReader.GetString("masteries"));

                MasteryList.Add(tmpMastery);
            }
        }
```

Mastery Class

```
class Mastery
{
    public int ID
    {
        set; get;
    }

    public byte Rank
    {
        set; get;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to follow but couldn't... Can you explain for the given sample data above what is the expected output?

Comment: I've updated the answer a little bit to try to be more clear which is kinda hard since english is not my first language. Please tell me if you don't understand and I'll get a friend to try to help me explain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to get external list where internal list with max count resides?

```
  List<Mastery> maxList = new List<Mastery>();
            var max = 0;

            foreach (var list in MasteryList)
            {
                var masteryList = list
                    .GroupBy(gp => new { gp.ID, gp.Rank })  // Agrupamos por ID y Rango
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())      // Ordenamos de mayor a menor
                    .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })    // Seleccionamos el valor y la cantidad de repeticiones
                    .ToList();

                var maxCurrent = masteryList.Max(x => x.Count);

                if (max < maxCurrent)
                {
                    maxList = list;
                    max = maxCurrent;
                }
            }
```

If that's the case then you should create a class `ConfigurationMastery` and use `List<ConfigurationMastery>` instead of `List<List<Mastery>>`. It will be easier for you to operate with this class. The above code can be simplified to use just linq.

Comment: I've updated the answer a little bit to try to be more clear which is kinda hard since english is not my first language. Please tell me if you don't understand and I'll get a friend to try to help me explain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you want. So, you have a list of List, with each item being a list that contains 10 masteries. Each of these masteries contains an ID and a rank.

You want to get the most popular masteries by grouping by both ID and rank as this constitutes a configuration. Finally, you want to order the list with the most frequently occurring configuration first. Try this:

```
var configurations = MasteryList.SelectMany(s => s)
                                .GroupBy(gp => new {gp.ID, gp.Rank} )
                                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                                .Select(x => new {
                                                    Id = x.Key.ID,
                                                    rank = x.Key.Rank,
                                                    count = x.Count()
                                                 })
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Exactly BUT instead of selecting each frequent mastery individually I need to select which are the most frequent SET of masteries

Comment: I don't even know if a List of List of objects its the best solution for this so Im open to other approaches.

Comment: So you want to know which list of masteries is most frequent?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I need to do :)

Comment: Can you have duplicate masteries within your list of 10 masteries?

Comment: No, in fact each list of masteries doesn't have any duplicate. If you see the data in the "masteries" field from the database you will notice that there isn't any mastery with the same ID in the same row.